# How to move wordpress website with ssl on localhost?

Tags: wordpress, ssl

Website with ssl on wordpress. Moved it on localhost, changed **wp-config**, changed  https://olddomain.ru to http://newdomain.ru.

But still have error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in browser and `Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01` in apache2 logs.Trying to start it via MAMP. How to disable SSL?

Answer (score 0):

This question relates to current and previous MAMP and MAMP PRO versions. MAMP PRO assists in replicating basic web host production environment on a users local Windows based system.

First, it's best to isolate the problem by disconnecting your system from internet.

Turning off GroupStart for Apache and MySQL by un-checking "Include MySQL in GroupStart" is another isolation problem solving technique:

https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Windows/Servers-and-Services/Apache/

https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Windows/Servers-and-Services/MySQL/

Emptying logs by erasing the log files prior to trying out the steps below is another way to isolate problems:

```
C:\MAMP\logs
```

Most local systems have AntiVirus program and the antivirus program usually has software firewall bundled. Be sure to add Web Server and HTTPS ports under ports and services of your choice of AntiVirus software.

**1. Custom Domain:**

First issue is related to assigning custom domains. A custom domain is assigned by modifying Windows Hosts file to point localhost host with IP 127.0.0.1 to a fictitious domain name.

Here is how the default hosts file looks like:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default

Here is the required modification:

hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 newdomain.ru
::0 localhost
```

::0 is the bus/port designation of a systems network adapter. Usually the first available network adapter software on a device has ::0 address.

After modifying hosts file be sure to flush dns by using Windows command prompt:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

**2. Location of Virtual Hosts data**

MAMP documentation recommends you store virtual Hosts data **outside of** default **C:\MAMP\htdocs** directory.

https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Windows/First-Steps/View-Localhost/

**3. Serverside language application**

MAMP recommends to serve serverside language applications such as WordPress on port 80 in your local development environment.

https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Windows/Troubleshooting/WordPress/WordPress1/